# hand over variable to function

Tags: javascript, html, function, google-chrome-extension

I would like to hand over the variable eventurl into the function fetchData, however this seems not to work and I do not know what the issue is. Would really appreciate if someone could help me.

```
async function fetchData(eventurl) {
    const res=await fetch (eventurl);
    const record=await res.json();
    stock = record.groups[0].sections
    document.getElementById("stock").innerHTML = JSON.stringify(stock);

}

chrome.tabs.query({'active': true, 'lastFocusedWindow': true}, function
(tabs) {
    var url = tabs[0].url;
    const pid = url.split("/");
    const eventpid = pid[5];
    const eventurl = "https://availability.ticketmaster.eu/api/v2/TM_CH/availability/"+eventpid+"?subChannelId=1";
    document.getElementById("link").innerHTML = eventurl;
    document.getElementById("event").innerHTML = eventpid;

})

fetchData();
```

Answer (score 0):

Your call to the function `fetchData()` is empty. You get a value for `eventurl` in the call to `chrome.tabs.query`'s function, but fetchData is outside, so you can't give it eventurl. If `chrome.tabs.query`'s function is synchronous, you could define `let eventurl` above it, set `eventurl` as you are doing, then call `fetchData(eventurl)` afterwards.

But since it looks like a callback that might run asynchronously, you could move `fetchData(eventurl)` inside `chrome.tabs.query`'s function.

Comment: I put fetchData into the chrome.tabs.query and it worked thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

Your variable `const eventurl` only exists inside the anynomous function block. So when you call your function `fetchData()` it doesn't know about variables from another block.

In your case, define the variable outside the function in order to use it

```
async function fetchData(eventurl) {
    const res=await fetch (eventurl);
    const record=await res.json();
    stock = record.groups[0].sections
    document.getElementById("stock").innerHTML = JSON.stringify(stock);

}

let eventurl = '';

chrome.tabs.query({'active': true, 'lastFocusedWindow': true}, function
(tabs) {
    var url = tabs[0].url;
    const pid = url.split("/");
    const eventpid = pid[5];
   eventurl = "https://availability.ticketmaster.eu/api/v2/TM_CH/availability/"+eventpid+"?subChannelId=1";
    document.getElementById("link").innerHTML = eventurl;
    document.getElementById("event").innerHTML = eventpid;

})

fetchData(eventurl);
```